# Is there a way to cast ObjectSet<table1> to ObjectSet<EntityObject>?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to make long codes short. The original codes does something following:

```
using (var context = new DataEntities())
{
context.Table1.Foreach(x =>{
    // Omit ... updating UI
    DoSomething(x);
    // Omit ... updating UI                    
});

context.Table2.Foreach(x =>
{
    // Omit ... updating UI
    DoSomething(x);
    // Omit ... updating UI                    
});

context.Table3.Foreach(x =>
{
    // Omit ... updating UI
    DoSomething(x);
    // Omit ... updating UI                    
});
// continue...
}
```

As you see, there is lots of similar code here. So, I thought I should refactor it though, it's pretty hard for me since I cannot cast context.Table1 to anything, for an example, to cast context.Table1 to `ObjectSet<EntityObject>` to implement a method which does all the same action for the tables.

I just want to put similar codes into a method, does anyone have a good idea?

Thanks in advance, 
Yoo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generics?

```
private void DoSomethingWithAnyTable<T>(ObjectSet<T> table) where T : EntityObject
{
    table.Foreach(x =>{ 
        // Omit ... updating UI 
        DoSomething(x); 
        // Omit ... updating UI                     
    });
}
```

Then

```
DoSomethingWithAnyTable(context.Table1);
DoSomethingWithAnyTable(context.Table2);
DoSomethingWithAnyTable(context.Table3);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `.Cast<SomeCommonType>` to get an `IEnumerable<T>` of them? Assuming there *is* come commonality.

Otherwise; perhaps just `IEnumerable`? (non-generic)